# how to access /bus/refresh actuator when this micro client is use spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have two micro client,they are both based on http basic security ,eurkea and spring cloud config(git repository).
I want to use spring cloud bus through "/bus/refresh" to reload each application's configuration.

#### But there will be always a authentication dialog when I enter "http://localhost:1234/bus/refresh" at browser address.

That is my problem.

Then I know "Because of the Spring Security dependency, HTTPS Basic authentication will also be enabled for Spring Boot Actuator endpoints. If you wish to disable that as well, 
 you must also set the management.security.enabled property to false." from network when I search the that problem's answer.

And I do what above say. Add "management.security.enabled = false" to application.properties that is at a client application(port:1234).

#### But When I retry enter "http://localhost:1234/bus/refresh" at browser address,there is "There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).

Request method 'GET' not supported" on page!!!

who know!!!

Comment: Most probably the call to the refresh endpoint has to be a POST call.

Comment: Thanks! It is really a post request!!

Answer (score 0):

According to source :

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus/blob/master/spring-cloud-bus/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bus/endpoint/RefreshBusEndpoint.java

for this end point you need to use POST method. And if you want security you can use management.security.enabled and also have management endpoints on different port management.port - this will separate your management endpoints from the rest of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer! It is really a post method from the source code ! But I can't use security according to your answer because there is always a authentication dialog when set management.security.enabled = true and management.port = 2222(another port)

Comment: Set management.security.enabled =false and there will be no authentication required.